# how to find the example for these sets?

Tags: real-analysis

There exist a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ for which its clo$A$, int$A$, int(clo$A$) and A are pairwise distinct.

pairwise distinct means they are not equal and

int$A$ means interior of A and

Clo$A$ means closure of $A$.

Comment: The has to be an limit point in the set, an limit point not in the set an interior point and a point that isn't an interior... and ... int(cloA) $\ne $int A$... hmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try $((0,1)\cap \mathbb Q) \cup (1, 2)$

clo$A = [0,2]$

int$A = (1,2)$

int(clo$A$) $ = (0,2)$.

clo(int$A$) $= [1,2]$

====

So here's how I thought about it.

Let clo(A) = [1,2] (just a stab; we'll change it later)

int(clo(A) = (1,2) $\ne$ A.  So... what A $\ne$  (1,2) has a closure of [1,2].  Well, that can't be open and must have some points dense in [1,2] so maybe (1,2) $\cap \mathbb Q$.

So A = (1,2) $\cap \mathbb Q$

int(A) = $\emptyset$

clo(A) = [1,2]

int(clo(A) = (1,2)

clo(int(A)) = $\emptyset$.

Well, let's just add a second (1,2) so clo(int(A)) not empty.

Comment: Trick is to try it pairwise int clo A $\ne$ int A implies some part of A is dense but not open.

Comment: now i think above also holds if clo(int$A$) is also included

Comment: that is just [1,2]